# Flutter Build Failing on Clean Installs

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator, build.gradle

Suddenly my emulators and physical device fail whenever launching applications - I have tried a bunch of different SDKs on new virtual devices in Android Studio and my Pixel 3a phone but it keeps failing on run or debug. It works fine on Chrome. I have tried editing my gradle files in various ways using code I found in similar questions but nothing works so far.

Here is what I get in debug console:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
```

Everything is looking good on Flutter Doctor.

---

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
PS I:\Flutter\build> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (3 weeks ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\BOXXUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\BOXXUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.57

• No issues found!
```

---

This is using a new install so pubspec file is autogenerated.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I have tried everything from Nougat to R in Android Studio SDK installer.

[image]

Here is the output of flutter build apk -v

```
PS I:\Flutter\build> flutter build apk -v
[  +81 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git tag --points-at c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[  +91 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[        ] 2.0.1
[  +45 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +42 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +85 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +59 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +79 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +78 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +65 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +188 ms] Generating I:\Flutter\build\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +99 ms] Building without sound null safety
[   +1 ms] For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
[  +65 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
[   +8 ms] Using gradle from I:\Flutter\build\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +2 ms] I:\Flutter\build\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +13 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +106 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [I:\Flutter\build\android/] I:\Flutter\build\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
-Ptarget=lib\main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=true assembleRelease
[+3724 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease
[   +2 ms] [  +77 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] [  +69 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +3 ms] [        ] c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[   +1 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git tag --points-at c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[   +2 ms] [  +77 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at c5a4b4029c0798f37c4a39b479d7cb75daa7b05c
[   +1 ms] [        ] 2.0.1
[   +1 ms] [  +38 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [  +37 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] [        ] origin/stable
[  +15 ms] [        ] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +5 ms] [  +33 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +6 ms] [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[   +1 ms] [  +76 ms] executing: [C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] [  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] [        ] stable
[   +2 ms] [  +57 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +76 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] [  +82 ms] Initializing file store
[        ] [  +39 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[        ] [   +8 ms] kernel_snapshot: Starting due to {}
[   +2 ms] [  +15 ms] C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk_product/ --target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Ddart.vm.profile=false
-Ddart.vm.product=true --aot --tfa --packages I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\package_config.json --output-dill
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\app.dill --depfile
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\kernel_snapshot.d package:build/main.dart
[+12883 ms] [+13366 ms] kernel_snapshot: Complete
[ +302 ms] [ +349 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[        ] [  +34 ms] executing: C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot --deterministic --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf
--elf=I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\armeabi-v7a\app.so --strip --no-sim-use-hardfp --no-use-integer-division
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\app.dill
[   +1 ms] [        ] aot_android_asset_bundle: Starting due to {}
[ +295 ms] [ +226 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +201 ms] [ +225 ms] executing: C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot --deterministic --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf--elf=I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\arm64-v8a\app.so --strip
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\app.dill
[   +1 ms] [        ] android_aot_release_android-x64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +184 ms] [ +245 ms] executing: C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64-release\windows-x64\gen_snapshot --deterministic --snapshot_kind=app-aot-elf
--elf=I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\x86_64\app.so --strip
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\app.dill
[+1104 ms] [+1085 ms] Running command: C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\const_finder.dart.snapshot --kernel-file
I:\Flutter\build\.dart_tool\flutter_build\57306c59d01b0730cda6c385aa8a8a22\app.dill --class-library-uri package:flutter/src/widgets/icon_data.dart --class-name IconData        
[ +508 ms] [ +520 ms] Running font-subset: C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\font-subset.exe
I:\Flutter\build\build\app\intermediates\flutter\release\flutter_assets\fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
C:\Users\BOXXUser\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\material_fonts\MaterialIcons-Regular.otf, using codepoints 58727 59828 59495 58791 58792 58974
[  +95 ms] [  +23 ms] aot_android_asset_bundle: Complete
[+5500 ms] [+5591 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm: Complete
[ +106 ms] [  +50 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[  +95 ms] [ +112 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm: Complete
[  +95 ms] [  +51 ms] android_aot_release_android-x64: Complete
[   +1 ms] [  +43 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-x64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +104 ms] [  +48 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-x64: Complete
[  +91 ms] [ +141 ms] android_aot_release_android-arm64: Complete
[   +1 ms] [  +35 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Starting due to {InvalidatedReason.inputChanged}
[ +108 ms] [  +50 ms] android_aot_bundle_release_android-arm64: Complete
[        ] [  +32 ms] _composite: Starting due to {}
[        ] [        ] _composite: Complete
[        ] [   +3 ms] Persisting file store
[        ] [  +15 ms] Done persisting file store
[        ] [  +17 ms] build succeeded.
[  +89 ms] [  +16 ms] "flutter assemble" took 22,546ms.
[        ] [   +4 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 1ms
[        ] [   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] [        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] [        ] exiting with code 0
[ +594 ms] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildRelease
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:extractProguardFiles
[        ] > Task :app:preReleaseBuild
[        ] > Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[ +693 ms] > Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
[ +206 ms] > Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
[        ] > Task :app:cleanMergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[ +504 ms] > Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
[  +92 ms] > Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
[ +206 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:generateReleaseResValues
[        ] > Task :app:generateReleaseResources
[+9198 ms] > Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
[ +300 ms] > Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease
[ +391 ms] > Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:processReleaseManifest
[ +106 ms] > Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease
[        ] > Task :app:mergeReleaseResources
[ +187 ms] > Task :app:compressReleaseAssets FAILED
[ +301 ms] > Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
[   +1 ms] > Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
[   +1 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compressReleaseAssets'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
[        ]    > I:\Flutter\build\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\release\out
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 38s
[   +1 ms] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 19 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 1 up-to-date
[ +523 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 39.1s)
[   +5 ms] "flutter apk" took 39,641ms.
[   +3 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:411:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:103:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #17     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #18     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +141 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 135ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Please post the output of `flutter build apk -v`

Comment: Also please post your pubspec.yaml lower half where you add assest entries. What version of android studio are you using? Did you upgrade recently? Finally what are your android gradle versions?

Comment: Thanks for that command. I have updated the post at the bottom. Also I am running on a new project install of Flutter so pubspec is generic settings.
name: build
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Comment: Since this is from a new flutter project instance the gradle version is the autogenerated 4.1.0 but I have tried changing this around.

I did update to Android Studio 4.1 today during the process of troubleshotting.

Comment: Something regarding the fonts keeps popping up, have you tried removing the fonts from your assets and from pubspec and attempting to build? We can try narrowing things down, assuming your have tried with the build gradle didn't work.

Comment: There are no font assets loading, even a fresh install of flutter doesn't work now. All the projects I have work fine on chrome but I cannot even deploy to actual device anymore

Comment: Any reason you are using `environment:  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` ?

Comment: That is what is generated on a fresh install for me. I have tried 2.1 but I actually use spread (...) operator so I need to have at least 2.7. Again though, I would expect the default flutter create application properties to work. Everything actually did work a few days ago which is frustrating too.